# Impliment Select Count in Codeigniter and echo the Results

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following query I will like to implement in CodeIgniter:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE status = "open";`

The result returned will be '1' and I will like to echo the result. I have the current code query:

```
$this->db->count_all_results();
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('status', 'Open');
$this->data['opentickets'] = $this->support_m->get();
```

I am trying to display the count result within the view. Any advice on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code to get the count the number of row with open status.

```
$this->db->where("status", 'Open');
$query = $this->db->get("tickets");
$this->data['opentickets'] = $query->num_rows();
```

Or You can use this one

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE status = "open"';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$this->data['opentickets'] =  $query->row_array()['COUNT(*)'];
```

Comment: Second did exactly what I want much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**You can run query in codeigniter :**

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE status = "open"';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$this->data['opentickets'] = $query->result_array();
```